# Catboost Missing Values Processing

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree, catboost

According to [catboost docs](https://catboost.ai/en/docs/concepts/algorithm-missing-values-processing) (python package), the algorithm handles numerical missing features in training by inputting the minimal value for the feature. But is does not mention if the same is true in predict. Does it peform the same handling?